# Is there really a tense-concord in English?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

For those who don't know what tense-concord is, it is the concord between the conditional part and the resultant part in a conditional sentence. For e.g.

(1)  If he ***comes***, the party ***will*** be lit. (Real conditional)

(2)  If he ***came*** here, the party ***would*** be lit. (Hypothetical, probably he is not gonna come)

My problem is that if I wanted to merge these two grammar rules, would it be ok or would it be too ungrammatical?

(3)  If he *comes*, the party *would* be lit. ( Here the speaker believes
his coming as a real thing but the party turning to be lit is not as strong
as it is in (1).

Can I use this type of sentence or would it be ungrammatical?

Comment: "... would it be ok or would it be too ungrammatical?" The term "ok" there—especially combined with "too ungrammatical"—is pretty squishy. In many circles it would be ordinary and unexceptionable. If you define the milieu the question can be answered, but in that case you will also have your answer. It is a matter of register, not grammar.

Comment: I would say it is a matter of grammar whose exact rules is in flux. Most of the time  I would use (1),  but neither of the first  two sentences conveys the same feeling that is in (3). And I have seen multiple times where  people have promoted the "tense-concord" explanation.

Comment: Then I think you have what you appear to consider an acceptable answer to your question. (Note that the number agreement, or lack of same, in the first question of your comment is a matter grammar *can* solve.)

Comment: Do you have any reference for 'tense-concord'? Afaik, agreement of tense refers to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_of_tenses#English) kind of thing. Your sentences are in different [moods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_mood), so generally, mixing them would be ungrammatical.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131104/discussion-on-question-by-english-more-exc-than-laws-is-there-really-a-tense-co).

Answer (score -1):

Since 'lit' is a subjective description, 'would' seems to fit better with it. It seems to enforce that the declaration is the speaker's opinion and is less formal than a forward-looking statement containing 'will'. I can agree that (3) makes grammatical sense for a conversational setting.

The comma in between the two phrases needs to engender a longer verbal pause where the speaker travels from a concrete conditional statement of whether he comes or not to imagining reminiscing about the party afterwards and perceiving it to have been lit because of his eventual coming to it.